# How to add endpoint behavior to open IIS hosted WCF service

Tags: wcf, iis, wcf-endpoint, endpointbehavior

I have an IIS hosted WCF service and I need to add an endpoint behavior to it. I can't just add it to web.config. (We need to support a plugin architecture and plugin writers won't have access to my web.config.) I tried putting this in the static constructor for the service:

```
var endpointDispatcher = OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher;
SilverlightFaultMessageInspector inspector = new SilverlightFaultMessageInspector();
endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
```

but it throws an exception saying "This value cannot be changed after the ServiceHost has opened." If I call host.Close() before adding the inspector object, it still throws the same exception.

I tried this as well:

```
var host = OperationContext.Current.Host;
host.Description.Endpoints[0].Behaviors.Add(new SilverlightFaultBehavior());
```

but it seems to have no effect. The endpoint behavior never gets called.

So is it possible to add an endpoint behavior to an IIS hosted WCF service?

Comment: Ladislav is right. I also found the following pages helpful for this subject: [MSDN: Custom Service Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) [MSDN: ServiceHostFactory Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory%28v=VS.90%29.aspx#Y228)

Answer (score 2):

Endpoint behavior can be added only before `ServiceHost` opens (starts hosting the service). So it requires resetting your service. Access to `ServiceHost` for services hosted in IIS is through custom `ServicHostFactory` which must be defined in .svc file. So you generally need something like custom `ServiceHostFactory` which will load behaviours from some repository and use them in `CreateServiceHost` method. Behaviours will be applied only after restarting application.

Comment: "After restarting the application"? So the application would start (e.g. Application_Start in global.asax gets called), ServiceHostFactory would create the serivce hosts, then the application would restart (calling Application_Start again)?

Is there no way to have the ServiceHostFactory create the service hosts with the endpoint behaviors initially?